# ssh to cisco router c3745

Tags: ssh, cisco-ios

I am able to ssh to the C3745 router.
But, by default it enters into the normal exec mode.
Is it possible to ssh directly into privilege exec mode.I don't want to use enable and then enter into the privilege mode.
I have given the user privilege level 15.

Thank-You

Comment: I want to run a command, that requires privilege, via a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my understanding that by default the VTY lines have a privilege level of "0". Seeing that you have already assigned a privilege level to your username the last thing I can think of is to modify this:

```
conf t
line vty 0 15
privilege level 15
exit
```

Now, if you login, you should be able to get directly into the enable mode. Please let me know if this works.

-Adam